# What should happen when Genie ISL 980 safety sensor shows four blinks?

Tags: garage-door-opener

What exactly do 4 blinks on a Genie garage door safety sensor mean; and, how should the door behave in response?

We have a Genie ISL 980 that is occasionally stopping and reversing about 12" above the floor (consistently in the same place). If I stop the door immediately after it reverses and push the button again, it will close. I'm trying to diagnose the cause (sticking roller, misaligned track, poorly aligned sensor, etc.).

The red sensor is always producing a 4-blink pattern. It exhibits this pattern when the door works as expected, when it reverses near the bottom, and when I cover the sensor (which should produce a two-blink patter, right)?

According to the manual, 4 blinks indicates either (1) "source not sending pulses", or (2) "source defective". However, that doesn't appear to be the case because the door will reverse immediately if I break the beam with my hand (the beam that the blink codes say isn't working :)

The actual symptom (reversing at a specific point in travel) suggests a track/roller problem, but I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Depends on the exact make and model. Should be disambiguated in the manual for the particular make and model. As for roller/track issues, disconnect the door from the closer and operate it by hand. Does it move smoothly and easily, does it stay put wherever you stop, etc. You should do that and check the operation of the  safety features every 6 months anyway. *i.e.* does it correctly stop and reverse if you put a 2x4 flat on the floor, and if you break the beam.

Comment: The code will probably vary with mfgr. Sweep off the bottom of the door to remove any cobweds that entrain dust and vegetation. These will sometimes cause reversal of the door as it approaches the sensor beam.

Comment: Have you checked your owner's manual? If you chucked it (like so many of us do) I'm sure it's available on this new-fangled internet thing.

Comment: I checked the owner's manual and clarified the question.